# Can't get page data from Jekyll plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to write a custom tag plugin for Jekyll that will output a hierarchical navigation tree of all the pages (not posts) on the site. I'm basically wanting a bunch nested `<ul>`'s with links (with the page title as the link text) to the pages with the current page noted by a certain CSS class.

I'm very inexperienced with ruby. I'm a PHP guy.

I figured I'd start just by trying to iterate through all the pages and output a one-dimensional list just to make sure I could at least do that. Here's what I have so far:

```
module Jekyll

  class NavTree < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      site = context.registers[:site]
      output = '<ul>'
      site.pages.each do |page|
        output += '<li><a href="'+page.url+'">'+page.title+'</a></li>'
      end
      output += '<ul>'

      output
    end
  end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('nav_tree', Jekyll::NavTree)
```

And I'm inserting it into my liquid template via `{% nav_tree %}`.

The problem is that the `page` variable in the code above doesn't have all the data that you'd expect. `page.title` is undefined and `page.url` is just the basename with a forward slash in front of it (e.g. for `/a/b/c.html`, it's just giving me `/c.html`).

What am I doing wrong?

**Side note:** I already tried doing this with pure Liquid markup, and I eventually gave up. I can easily iterate through `site.pages` just fine with Liquid, but I couldn't figure out a way to appropriately nest the lists.

Comment: I created [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/548) to see if anybody there knows the answer.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get the nesting working? I'd love to see the final code if so

Comment: @Brand Unfortunately, I never got around to finishing it.

Comment: I managed to hack the hierachical page tree together. It's not pretty but I've posted it here: https://gist.github.com/3536551 in case anyone else stumbles on this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
module Jekyll

  # Add accessor for directory
  class Page
          attr_reader :dir
  end


  class NavTree < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      site = context.registers[:site]
      output = '<ul>'
      site.pages.each do |page|
        output += '<li><a href="'+page.dir+page.url+'">'+(page.data['title'] || page.url) +'</a></li>'
      end
        output += '<ul>'

      output
    end
  end

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('nav_tree', Jekyll::NavTree)
```

Comment: With this code, I get `Liquid error: can't convert nil into String`.

Comment: You probably had a page without a title, so that page.data['title'] is nil. Replace w/ e.g. (page.data['title'] || page.url) .

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. You were correct. I had a page without a title. Your solution works.

Answer (score 4):

`page.title` is not always defined (example: `atom.xml`). You have to check if it is defined. Then you can take `page.name` or not process the entry...

```
def render(context)
  site = context.registers[:site]
  output = '<ul>'
  site.pages.each do |page|
    unless page.data['title'].nil?
      t = page.data['title']
    else
      t = page.name
    end
    output += "<li><a href="'+page.dir+page.url+'">'+t+'</a></li>"
  end
  output += '<ul>'
  output
end
```

Comment: Shorten that unless..end a bit to: `t = page.data['title'] || page.name`

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar problem where the error "cannot convert nill into string" is just blowing my head. My config.yml file holds a line something like this " **baseurl: /paradocs/jekyll/out/** " now thats for my local for a server i need to make that beseurl empty and the error starts to appear in build time so finally i have to made " **baseurl: /** " .. And that's did my job.